# image doesnt open in browser. Asp.net image control and imageurl set and visible in designer

Tags: asp.net, image, webforms

I have a image control on a asp.net page and the imageurl is set. The image shows normal in the designer but doesnt open in the browser?? What can be wrong with it? What else should be set then the image url???

Help much appreciated

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div class="style1">
   <h1>A Basic Website<asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" Height="93px" 
           ImageAlign="Right" ImageUrl="~/App_LocalResources/Winter.jpg" Width="263px" />

    </h1>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you sooooooo much for the help, I found the solution, I was using app_resources folder which didnt work, but when I renamed the folder it did.... so thanks for taking the time to show the way :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<img src="~/Images/mypic.jpg" alt="My Pic" runat="server" />
```

Use the tilda (~/) operator and the runat attribute so that the path resolves on the server side.

I also suggest not using designer view - use code view and your browser for regular design work. Try the Firefox [Web Dev Toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer-toolbar/).

To use the image control:

```
 <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" 
        ImageUrl="~/Images/ASPdotNET_logo.jpg" 
        AlternateText="ASP.NET Logo">
```

Here's a [walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3has1x30%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)...